# Uniswap fork: remove liquidity error

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, erc-20, uniswap

I am trying to fork uniswap. And I have a problem when liquidity is removed. Problem in [UniswapERC20](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol#L81). I don't know what's wrong.

Step by step (repeatedly for Rinkeby and Ropsten):

1. Copy Uniswap Factory and Router from etherscan
2. Go to Remix
3. Add this string for testnet in the factory contract:

   bytes32 public constant INIT_CODE_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode));
4. Compile. Set **feeToSetter** address and deploy (save init code hash and Factory address)
5. Set **feeTo** address
6. Replace init code hash in the Router contract
7. Compile. Set Factory and WETH addresses and deploy (save addresses)
8. Replace addresses in the interface and start local server
9. Work test:

- Create pair: ok
- Swaps: ok:
- Add liquidity: ok
- Remove part or all liquidity: fail (error -> **UniswapV2: INVALID_SIGNATURE**)

More info:

- Etherscan Geth VM Trace Transaction:
  `{ "type": "CALL", "from": "0x57d49704f453cdd2b995280d9d7f557e42847d82", "to": "0x0b024ab7886e87dde36103d6f4a53e35456d5341", "value": "0x0", "gas": "0x2d6978", "gasUsed": "0x7460", "input": "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", "output": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c556e697377617056323a20494e56414c49445f5349474e415455524500000000", "error": "execution reverted", "time": "11.0239ms", "calls": [ { "type": "CALL", "from": "0x0b024ab7886e87dde36103d6f4a53e35456d5341", "to": "0xa5baae8372d14ee9394dace03cb53222db293aee", "value": "0x0", "gas": "0x2ca8bc", "gasUsed": "0x68ea", "input": "0xd505accf00000000000000000000000057d49704f453cdd2b995280d9d7f557e42847d820000000000000000000000000b024ab7886e87dde36103d6f4a53e35456d5341000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000470de4df81f06000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005ffd5ee0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c9f3cd9721b08bacde6ec671f9186f0e621990760d1b73009516a8db5f2403e5773b73eb0cddc9d288a1b2d5cef84d1c8f4475d5d90a33dc9615e81f982499281", "error": "execution reverted" } ] }`
- [Transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x84bdbda819d678b985c8ea9c1b89e16b936ad07bb2cee144e4471344e89a7e02)

Comment: I am getting "ds-math-sub-underflow" error while removing liquidity. Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @Prachi? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change you LP token name in file located at

```
/src/pages/RemoveLiquidity/index.ts
```

search for domain object:

```
const domain = {
      name: 'Spooky LP', // <= here place your LP token smart contract name
      version: '1',
      chainId,
      verifyingContract: pair.liquidityToken.address,
    }
```